React Native / Expo go [TypeError: Network request failed] on fetch
I'm trying to send requests to an API on a local server. My dev computer is on 192.168.8.102 and the API is on 192.168.8.100.
A simple fetch request from my app to the API creates a [TypeError: Network request failed]
Sidenote: The API works fine in Insomnia.
  useEffect(function() {
    fetch("https://192.168.8.100/clip/v2/resource/device", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "hue-application-key": "<my api key>"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => console.log("json", json))
      .catch(err => console.error("fetch error", err))
  }, [])

I've used expo-network to sniff out my device IP, which is indeed 192.168.8.102.
How do I send requests to the API? I cannot figure this out.
The API I am trying to send requests to is the Philips Hue bridge API, which I have worked with on web without these kinds of issues.
